# Why Secondary Internal HDD Vanishes/Reappears Randomly In Windows 10 , Dell?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, hardware-failure

I am using dell inspiron 7570 laptop, it consist of 120 GB S-SD (solid-state drive) & 1 tb HDD (hard disk drive) but some times after turning-on or re-start my laptop HDD will disappear and appear randomly, after 1 or 2 days works fine for some while, again the same problem appears.

Where is the problem exactly happening?

Comment: How old is the laptop? Any possibility the HDD may be failing? Loose connection? There are too many things that could cause it.. if it is still under warranty - definitely go to Dell and get it checked.

Comment: It is a year old laptop, i given it in dell service center and they replaced HDD  and then updated drivers but again after 3 months facing same problem, I have visited again dell they too were not sure what to do, this is the end of my warranty, what if this repeats again?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like a hardware issue.  However, the first thing I would do would be to confirm this.  I would boot a Linux live USB/CD/DVD and see if the problem still persists.

If the problem no longer occurs, then there is a OS/software issue.  Resolving the issue would take some more troubleshooting.

If the problem still occurs, it is most likely a hardware issue.  The problem could be a faulty SATA controller, bad solder joints, broken traces, etc.  These issues are not really user fixable.  Nor are they fixable by Dell.  The simplest and most cost effective solution is to replace the laptop's motherboard.

If your laptop is still under warranty, I would ask for a motherboard replacement.  Since the hard drive was replaced and the issue is still occurring, replacing the motherboard *should* resolve the issue.  Talk to Dell support, tell them you are still having the issue after the drive was replaced, and request a replacement motherboard be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if there were any disk errors logged.

1. Hold the Windows Key+X on your keyboard then click Event Viewer.
2. Expand Windows Logs and click System
3. On the right click Filter Current Log...
4. Drop down Event Sources and tick 'disk' and 'Disk' and hit OK
5. Review any shown logs to see if there are errors

These log entries will generally tell you if a disk has bad blocks or errors, or possibly if the drive was removed unexpectedly.

Under the same menu (Windows Key+X) you will see 'Disk Management' - If the drive has disappeared from Windows Explorer however still shows under the disk management console, it could be a partition error, in which case you would need to run a check dick over the drive. You can perform this by the same menu (Windows Key+X) and select 'Windows PowerShell (Admin)' OR 'Command Prompt (Admin)'.

Accept the permissions to run in the UAC prompt that shows.
In the new window that has appeared type: `chkdsk D: /R` - This is assuming the drive you are having troubles with has a drive letter of D:. Change this to which ever letter is disappearing.